# Javascript using Object values in a function

Tags: javascript

Could someone tell me how this would be properly coded in Javascript? Ive tried googling but my JS vocabulary is borderline illiterate.

```
var myVar = {foo : num};

function myFunction(x) 
{
    newNum = myVar(num) - x;
    if newNum >= num
        console.log("Positive Change");
    else
        console.log("Your value is now (newnum)");
}
```

Comment: You use dot-notation: `obj.propery`, but I don't see how you could not of found that.

Comment: start here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
newNum = myVar.foo - x;
```

To access a property of an object, you use `objectVariable.propertyName`. If the property name is in a variable, you can do `objectVariable[propertyVariable]`.

Parentheses after a variable are used to call it as a function.